# Problems getting a nested select right

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to produce a query where one column gives me a true/false in case 1 or more records exists in a table. Here are the three tables and the desired output:

TABLE 1: USER

```
ID | NAME  | CREATE_DATE  
1  | Chris | 01.01.2017   
2  | Mark  | 05.02.2017
```

TABLE 2: ENTRY

```
ID | USER_ID | ENTRY_CONTENT  
1  |    1    | "Some string"   
2  |    1    | "Another string"  
3  |    2    | "something something dark side"
```

TABLE 3: RATE

```
ID1 | ID2 | WINNER  
1   |  2  |  1
```

ID1 and ID2 in the table RATE are IDs from ENTRY. Imagine that I show you a pair of entries a user made and asks them which is better. Their choice is stored in "winner"

My query should give me the following:

```
USER ID | Amount of entries | RATINGS Y/N
```

For every USER, i want to see their ID, how many entries they have made, and whether or not they did any ratings.

So in the case of the above:

```
USER ID | Amount of entries | RATINGS Y/N  
1       |     2             |  1  
2       |     1             |  0
```

Here is the code:

```
SELECT    u.id, 
          ( 
                 SELECT Count(*) AS count 
                 FROM   entry 
                 WHERE  ( entry.user_id = u.id)
          ) AS "Amount of entries", 
          EXISTS 
          ( 
                 SELECT id1 
                 FROM   rate r 
                 WHERE  r.id1=e.id 
                 AND    e.id=u.id) AS "Ratings Y/N" 
FROM      "user" u 
LEFT JOIN entry e on u.id=e.user_id 
GROUP BY  u.id
```

I get the following error:
ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column e.id from outer query
LiNE 5 ... ID1 from RATE r where r.id1=e.id and e..

I am a beginner and did not find any solution to this problem. I would be grateful for a solution and a short explanation of WHY it failed and which concepts i should have a look into to. Thank you.

Comment: instead of `ID` name your field `entry_id` and `user_id` that way is much easier to find the related table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't clear how you define `RATINGS Y/N` because not sure what are ID1 and ID2 or the Winner result. So that calculation is just a guest. Best way to test it is do the same query to test the JOIN's without aggregations and check the resulting set is the correct.

I use user_id, entry_id as join field to make it clear. If the join aren't the want you intent should be easy to fix.

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       COUNT( e.user_id ) as total_entries,
       MAX( CASE WHEN r.winner IS NULL 
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
            END) as RATINGS
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN entries e
  ON u.user_id = e.user_id
LEFT JOIN rates r
  ON e.entry_id = r.entry_id1
  OR e.entry_id = r.entry_id2
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: Your count wasn't correct but that wasn't the question. MAX() did end up work.

Would you care to explain to me why?

Comment: Well not sure because I dont have the data. But because you are doing left join, you either have data or `NULL` so `MAX()` will give you the bigger result or NULL if not data.

Comment: thank you. Looking at it now, it is very easy to understand.